# Multiple random images

Tags: php

I am using `DOMDocument` to call an RSS Feed. Everything looks great, but I am wanting to use a set list of random images for my items.

Problem is, it needs to be in a `foreach` argument.  How do I do this?

My site is [here](http://callofduty-online.com/new/site/).

The code:

```
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://www.rssmix.com/u/2759612/rss.xml');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 40;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date'])); ?>

    <div id="post" class="box">
        <a href="<?php echo $link ?>">
            <div id="item"></div>
                <div class="date">Modern Warfare 3</div>
                <div class="desc"><span class="green"><?php echo $date ?></span><br /><?php echo $title ?></div>
        </a>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to read or write to the rss DOM? Also provide some code

Comment: No. I can give you the URL to the work in progress. I will post the code in another comment.

Comment: Edit the question and put the code *there*.

Comment: The code is too big to fit in here.

Comment: At this moment, I am just using a temporary image. I tried pulling the actual image from the RSS, but couldn't get it to work. I am pretty good at HTML, some PHP, graphics, and CSS, and a little jQuery. Horrible at XML, JavaScript, and stuff like that.

Comment: Where do you want to get the images from? There are no images in the RSS stream.

Comment: I was wondering if I could display random images instead. You've seen the site right? It kind of have to have images to look right,  I was just going to have 40 images in like a folder, and I need a script to display them randomly, but only problem is the PHP code I'm calling the feed for is in a 'foreach' format. Kind of get where I'm coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is you could first have an array of images and randomizing it first with the paths. It is the easiest way if you don't want to dive into looping of all the files in the folder etc.

**This is just an example, may not be the best practice.**

```
$images = array("yourfolder/image.jpg","yourfolder/image2.jpg"); 
shuffle($images);
```

Followed by modifying your item to include the image.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {

    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'image' => $images[$i];
        );

    array_push($feed, $item);
    $i++;
}

for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date'])); ?>
    $image = $feed[$x]['image'];

<div id="post" class="box">
    <a href="<?php echo $link ?>">
        <div id="item"></div>
            <div class="date">Modern Warfare 3</div>
            <div class="desc"><span class="green"><?php echo $date ?></span><br /><?php echo $title ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: I was thinking of just defining a new variable and shuffle, only problem is I don't want them to repeat. However, I guess they shouldn't because I am shuffling through them. I will give it a try and post my results.

Answer (score 0):

Final code.

```
<?php

    $images = array("img/no_img.png","img/img_1.png","img/img_2.png","img/img_3.png"); 
    shuffle($images);

    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://www.rssmix.com/u/2759612/rss.xml');
    $feed = array();

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'image' => $images[$i],
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
        $i++;
    }
    $limit = 40;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $image = $feed[$x]['image'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date'])); ?>

    <div id="post" class="box">
        <a href="<?php echo $link ?>">
            <div id="item"></div>
            <img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="date">Modern Warfare 3</div>
                <div class="desc"><span class="green"><?php echo $date ?></span><br /><?php echo $title ?></div>
        </a>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```